# How to use Charles Proxy on Mac to intercept network requests of another device

Tags: proxy

I'm trying to intercept the network requests of my smart MP3 player. I'm currently using Charles proxy, and I saw that Android configuration requires setting a proxy, but my MP3 player doesn't support proxies.

Is there any way to intercept the network requests of my MP3 player?